# Can I save an id from API using shared preferences where I can retrieve it's contents e.g. name, age, location, ect

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

In the preferences I would like to save the user id so that in next page I could use its id to create a profile page for the user. as of now I can only pass the name of the user. I want to somehow get the id so that I can pull another json file for profile page

```
void login() async {
    if (userController.text.isNotEmpty && 
passController.text.isNotEmpty) {
    var postUrl = "http://serverUrl";
    var auth = "auth.json";
    var login = postUrl + auth;
  

    var data = jsonEncode(
        {"username": userController.text, "password": 
passController.text});

    http.Response res = await http.post(Uri.parse(login),
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, body: data);

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      final resData = jsonDecode(res.body);
      String message = (resData['response']['message']);
      String fName = (resData['response']['member_info']['fname']);
      String lName = (resData['response']['member_info']['lname']);
      String fullName = fName + " " + lName;
    

    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text(message),
    ));
    pageRoute(fullName);
  } else if (res.statusCode == 400) {
    final resData = jsonDecode(res.body);
    String message = (resData['response']['message']);
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text(message),
    ));
  }
} else {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
    content: Text("No username or password"),
  ));
 }
}

 void pageRoute(String fullName) async {
   SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   await pref.setString("data", fullName);
   Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
     CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => const ProfilePage()),
     (route) => false
    );
  }
}
```

//Here is my code for the Profile page where I will retrieve the stored data in the shared preferences

```
class _ProfileInfoState extends State<ProfileInfo> {
 String fullName = "";
 late int memberId;

 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
 getData();
 }

void getData() async {
//Fetching of Data
 SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 setState(() {
  fullName = pref.getString("data")!;
  memberId = pref.getInt("data")!;
  });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
  drawer: NavigationDrawerWidget(),
  appBar: AppBar (
    title: SizedBox(
      height: 45,
      width: 180,
      child: Image.asset('images'),
    ),
    elevation: 10.0,
    flexibleSpace: Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [Colors.deepOrangeAccent, Colors.green],
          begin: Alignment.bottomRight,
          end: Alignment.topLeft
        ),
      ),
    ),
    actions: [
    IconButton(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart_rounded),
      onPressed: () {
        // print('cart');
      },
    ),
    IconButton(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.home),
      onPressed: () {
        // print('home');
      },
    ),
  ],
  ),
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
            child: Text(
              "Welcome User",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 150,
          ),
          Text("Name: $fullName"),
          Text("Name: $memberId"),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 35,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
 );  
}
```

}

Comment: Can you share a minimal reproducible code to help you?

Comment: You really should create a data class holding all the fields in the JSON object. Also create methods `toJson()` and `fromJson()` to go along with it. Then you can pass an instance of this class to the Page widget via the Navigator.

Comment: @RoslanAmir I've tried doing that but I am getting Internal linkedhashmap error

Comment: If you post your sample JSON string for the response I will give you the data class and give you an updated `login` method and `ProfileInfo` widget.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can save your id which you retrieve from the api to shared preference

but Before saving the id to shared preference you need to check if id is not-null then it will save other wise not save to shared preference.. if you share your code then i will solve it for you if you want

Comment: I have already edited my question. thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you are passing `fullName` in **pageRoute** method, you can also pass the `id` of user (If you are getting in response).

For example:

```
int id = (resData['response']['member_info']['id']); //if key is 'id'

pageRoute(id, fullName);
```

And you function will be like:

```
void pageRoute(int id, String fullName) async {
   SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   await pref.setString("data", fullName);
   await pref.setInt("id", id);

   Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
     CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => const ProfilePage()),
     (route) => false
    );
  }
}
```

Then you can use it on **ProfilePage** as you are using **fullName**.

Do let me know if you need any other help. Thanks!

Comment: I get an error LateInitializationError:Field 'id'